# Using pojo instead of objecMapper nodes

Tags: java, json, pojo, ebean, objectmapper

I am creating json as per my requirement using ObjectMapper. I choose this as I have existing DTO. can someone please let me know doing this using POJO instead of creating objects by object nodes?

Below is my existing code snippet which i would like to re-write using POJO.

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
 mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
    ObjectNode orderNode = new ObjectNode(mapper.getNodeFactory());
    ObjectNode order = new ObjectNode(mapper.getNodeFactory());
    ArrayNode requests = new ArrayNode(mapper.getNodeFactory());
    for (OrderDto dto : searchResults.data) {
      order.put("order-id", dto.id);
      order.put("order-ext-id", dto.externalId);
      order.put("from-address", dto.from == null ? null : dto.from.placeId);
      order.put("to-address", dto.to == null ? null : dto.to.placeId);
      order.put("available-time", dto.availableBy);
      order.put("committed-time", dto.committedBy);
      for (RequestDto requestDto : dto.requests) {
        ObjectNode request = new ObjectNode(mapper.getNodeFactory());
        request.put("request-id", requestDto.id);
        request.put("request-ext-id", requestDto.externalId);
        requests.add(request);
      }
      order.set("requests", requests);
      orderNode.set("order", order);
    }
    return ok(orderNode);
```